# How can I create a reset button for this game?

Tags: javascript, button, reset

I have my current code posted, I'm trying to create a reset button. A button has already been created in my HTML,  and I'm grabbing it at the bottom, and adding an event listener, which isn't working for some reason, also trying to figure out the correct code to add it for my game resets when the button is clicked.  However having a difficult time with the syntax.

```
 // Array of words
const words = ['planet', 'stars', 'astroid', 'moon', 'satilite', 'orbit', 'universe', 'umbra', 'lunar', 'space', 'astronomy', 'eclipse', 'nebula', 'mars', 'meteorite']

// guesses Array
let myGuesses = []


//variables
let wordSpace = ' - '
let guess = ' '
let space; //number of spaces in word


//score
let tries = 10
let counter ;
//Get random word
let index = Math.floor(Math.random()* words.length)  

//play function
function play() {
    let userInput = prompt(`would you like to play spaceman? (Y/N)`, "Y")
    console.log(words[index])
    
        
        
    for(let i = 0; i < words[index].length; i++){
        console.log(words[0][i])
            
        let div = document.createElement('div')
        div.classList.add('letters')
        div.innerHTML=' - '//words[0][i]
        document.querySelector('.word-space').append(div)
           
    
    }                                        
}
//handle click function, inactivates buttons, and changes color to grey; once clicked
let handleclick = e => {
    e.target.removeEventListener('click', handleclick)
    e.target.style.backgroundColor= 'grey'
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML)
    myGuesses.push(e.target.innerHTML)
    console.log(myGuesses)
    console.log(words[index].includes(e.target.innerHTML))
    if(words[index].includes(e.target.innerHTML)){
        document.querySelector('.word-space').innerHTML= '  '
        // let correct = document.createElement('ul')
        

        for(let i = 0; i < words[index].length; i++){
            
            // correct.setAttribute('id','correctLetters' )
            // let guess= document.createElement('li')
            // guess.setAttribute('class','guess')
            console.log(words[0][i])
             let div = document.createElement('div')
             div.classList.add('letter')
              if (myGuesses.includes(words[index][i])){
                div.innerHTML = words[index][i]
                        
                                 
            } else {
                div.innerHTML = ' - '
            }
                
            document.querySelector('.word-space').append(div)
            
        }
        getNumOfTries()         
            
              
} else {    
    tries -- 
    getNumOfTries()
    
}
                        
}
function ans () {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.letter')
    buttons.forEach(letter => letter.addEventListener('click',handleclick))
     
    
    
    


    
}
ans()



 

function getNumOfTries (){
    console.log(tries)
    const showTries = document.querySelector('#myTries')
    showTries.innerHTML = ' You have ' + tries + ' tries'
    if(tries < 1){
       setTimeout(() =>{prompt(`Would you like to try again? (Y,N)`, 'Y')
       showTries.innerHTML = 'You loose!'

       },2000) 
      
       
        
               
    }
    // if(tries > 0  && words[index].length === myGuesses.length) {
    
        if(tries > 0  && Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.letters')).every(letter => letter.innerHTML !== ' - ')) {
            // showTries.innerHTML = 'You Win!'
             setTimeout(() =>{alert(`You Win!`)
             showTries.innerHTML = 'You Win!'
     
             },1000)
            
        
        }
        
        
        
}




//reset game
let tryAgain = document.querySelector('.Try-Again')
tryAgain.addEventListener('clcik', play)
prevent
div.innerHTML=' - '//words[0][i]
document.querySelector('.word-space').append(div)


    

   

play()
```

Comment: You have a small typo in the event name 'clcik'.

Comment: So this should be closed as typo ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo there :)

```
tryAgain.addEventListener('clcik', play)
```

some notes to the written code:

- you don't need to reference the element, if you're not going to use it elsewhere, just do:

  document.querySelector('.Try-Again')?.addEventListener('click', play);
- i'm not sure about what the "prevent" should do here
- you haven't defined a global reference to a "div" parameter that you want to use at:

  div.innerHTML=' - '//words[0][i]
- use semicolon ';' by the end of each executed code for better code clarity + checkout some coding standards
- use code editors like **Visual Studio code** or other tools - they usually have some basic code formatter (learn they shortcuts, it will optimize your coding process) + other usefull features like clicking through defined param references etc.

Comment: Yes i forgot to remove some code before posting the prevent, and the dive were previous attempts,  I’ll give your solution a try